# how to build a simple two columns style?

Tags: two-column, double-sided

I am looking for a simple two columns style with font size 12. Most of what i found are complex or difficult to use as a beginner!

Could you advise please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the twocolumn and the 12pt document class option:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,12pt]{article}
```

Comment: Thank you! it works fine! only i got a wide margin in both side, how can i make the page full with less margin space.Thanks

Comment: You will have to be more precise on which margin width you want to change -- the one between the columns or the one at the page borders.